# How to convert Standard Snapshot to Archive Snapshot in GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Google has recently drastically raised snapshot storage prices (almost a 3x factor), and to offset that, they have added an alternative snapshot storage service, "Archive Snapshots" which are comparable in price to the original "Standard Snapshots".

However, I cannot find any way to convert existing Standard Snapshots to Archive Snaphots.

I guess I could recreate a disk for each of the dozens of snapshots we have, and then create a new Archive Snapshot manually for each of the disks. But this seems extremely cumbersome and unnecessary.

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler method, or a way to automate this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no direct conversion from Standard to Archive snapshot.

You may submit your query as a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, for feature requests there is no guarantee of any time frame for updates or that the requested feature will be implemented.

Comment: Thanks. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/281669775